# Как просмотреть __doc__ атрибута?

Tags: python

```
>>> class C(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._x = value
    def _getx(self):
        return self._x
    def _setx(self, value):
        self._x = value
    def _delx(self):
        del self._x
    x = property(_getx, _setx, _delx, doc="I'm the 'x' property.")


>>> obj = C(123)
>>> obj.x
123
>>> obj.x.__doc__
"int(x=0) -> integer\nint(x, base=10) -> integer\n\nConvert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments\nare given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point\nnumbers, this truncates towards zero.\n\nIf x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,\nbytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the\ngiven base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded\nby whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.\nBase 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer  literal.\n>>> int('0b100', base=0)\n4"
>>>
```

Как увидеть *"I'm the 'x' property.""*, а не docstring для *int*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте:

- `C.x.__doc__`
- `type(obj).x.__doc__`